# SELECT odd syntaxes in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a large MySQL database table with a lot of city names, 90% of them are valid entries, but some of them are written in a ... not valid way.
For example the valid way is juste "CITYNAME" but some of them are like "(CITY NAME)(COUNTRY)" or just "(CITY NAME)" so I just wanna `SELECT` all the entries that are not written the valid way. 
I don't know if that's specific enough don't hesitate to ask me for some precise elements. 
And please help I have no idea how to build my SQL query.

```
CREATE TABLE cities(
   name    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO cities(name) VALUES ('ORLANDO');
INSERT INTO cities(name) VALUES ('(CHARLOTTE)');
INSERT INTO cities(name) VALUES ('(PHOENIX)(USA)');
INSERT INTO cities(name) VALUES ('AUSTIN(USA)');
INSERT INTO cities(name) VALUES ('TENNESSEE NASHVILLE');
```

So here are some examples of the different kinds of entries that I have to deal with.
I don't know how to describe the desired output, that'd just be a list of odd syntaxes, with or without the brackets.
The whole point is to delete those odd entries, but I have to `SELECT` them before doing so. And I also won't be the one deleting them, just gotta `SELECT`.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected results

Comment: Edit your question and provide specific sample data (in a tabular format) and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: I recommend to make an [MCVE] with sample data in the shape of a line of "create table ..." and some lines of "insert ..."; i.e. NOT in tabular form.

Comment: Ok i'll do that hold up.

Comment: Please also show desired output. Especially in the case of several pairs of `()`, describe the content of which pair you want. I guess you want the content of the first pair and ignore the rest.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited that in, forgot o mention that.

Comment: Either way, i'd want a "(CHARLOTTE)", "(PHOENIX)(USA)" or without the brackets if that's doable.
And for that specific example, "ORLANDO" doesn't have to be in the select since it written in the syntax I want.

Comment: To write a query won't be much of a problem. What must be done is that **you define the rules**. When exactly do you consider a string a valid city and when not? Is it about certain characters in the string? At certain positions even? Is one blank in the string okay? Two? Three? Precisely describe the rules, then see if you are able to write the according query or not.

Comment: I guess 'TENNESSEE NASHVILLE' is invalid? Would 'NASHVILLE, TENNESSEE' be valid? Or only "NASHVILLE"? If 'TENNESSEE NASHVILLE' is invalid, how to technically find this out? It's certainly not about the blank, because 'SAN DIEGO' must be valid. So: Can you define watertight rules on how to tell valid from invalid cities from the strings alone?

Comment: I gotta admit that's confusing, but for some reasons SAN DIEGO would be written 'SAN-DIEGO' so I guess adding blanks to my query would give me the result I want ?
And in the insert I provided only the first one is valid.

Comment: @Seb, My answer manage the space problem, 'TENNESSEE NASHVILLE' isn't valid but 'SAN-DIEGO' is valid with my query.

Comment: @ThibautB. I just didn't quite understand what the  " regexp '^[A-Z-]+$' " was doing. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Seb, ```'^[A-Z-]+$'``` mean that all the city names who are not respect the format ```"AAAA" or "AAAA-AAA"``` where ```A``` represent an uppercase letter, is considered as invalid.

Comment: @ThibautB. Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you try something like

```
Select * from cities where name like '(%';
```

If the problem is the parenthesis.. then everything that starts with a parenthesis will be selected

EDIT:

```
Select * from cities where name like '%(%' or name like '%)%';
```

It gives every line that contains a ( OR a )

EDIT2: some explanation

The character '%' replaces any string. So if you put like '%*randomthing*%', it will look for everything that look like anystring_randomthing_anystring. I hope i made this clear

Comment: I'm gonna add 1 or 2 example of other odd syntaxes that appears in my table. There's no only parenthesis. And some of them doesn't strat by parenthesis. Check my edit.

Comment: Similar to the @Yunnosch answer that worked, nice to see that there is another way to do it. 
Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Though if you understand what the person is explaining in an answer, you should be able to adapt.. once you had the like'(%' it was not hard to adapt, with a few research.

Comment: What if I want to select those that also have blanks ? Like the last INSERT I provided.

Comment: or name like '% %' ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions with output:

```
select * from cities where instr(name,')') or instr(name,'(');
(CHARLOTTE)
(PHOENIX)(USA)
```

This looks for anything which contains "(" or ")" anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked and that's pretty much the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySql, so you can do:

```
select *
from cities
where name not regexp '^[A-Z-]+$';
```

The `not regexp '^[A-Z-]+$'` means all the city names that don't respect the format `"AAAA"` or `"AAAA-AAAAA"` (where `A` represent an uppercase letter) is considered as invalid.